# Loop till correct input

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
System.out.println("What hero are you playing?");
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
String character = console.next();
String[] hero = {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"};

if(Arrays.asList(hero).contains(character)) {
    System.out.println("hero selected: "+ character);
}
else {
    System.out.println("hero not found");
}
```

I'd like it to run this until a correct hero name is enetered. If a wrong name is entered it should ask for it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to loop an unknown amount of times. (until a condition you define is met). You're looking for the 'while'-loop. Since you always want to do the same thing while the input isn't a correct name, this part of the code should go inside the while loop. When a correct name is entered, you want to move along in the code. So place the handling of that event outside the loop:

```
System.out.println("What hero are you playing?");
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
/**you have a second scanner, but it's using the same input source. You
should only have one scanner for System.in, maybe call the variable userInput**/
Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
//String character = console.next(); you only take input from the user once, this needs to go into a loop.
String character; //do this instead
String[] hero = {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"};
while(!Arrays.asList(hero).contains(character = console.next())) {//changed to a while loop. This will keep running until the condition evaluates to false.
    System.out.println("hero not found"); //notice the '!' in the condition check. this means if next console input is NOT contained in the hero array.
}
System.out.println("hero selected: "+ character); //if we're no longer in the loop, it means we found a correct hero name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    System.out.println("What hero are you playing?");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
    String character;
    String[] hero = {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"};
    do{
        character = console.next();
        if(Arrays.asList(hero).contains(character)) {
            System.out.println("hero selected: "+ character);
            break;
        }
        else {System.out.println("hero not found");
        }    
    }while (true);
```